# Allocate terminal with child_process

Tags: linux, node.js, ssh, terminal

I'm using `child_process` to run a script that ultimately calls

```
ssh -t server "sudo command"
```

I get back:

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>   sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Is there any way to make the process' `stdin` a terminal?  It's being run like so;

```
var proc = child_process.spawn(pathToCommand, ["args"]);
proc.stdout.on("data", function (data) {                          
    socket.emit("running", "" + data);                                      
});                                                                         

proc.stderr.on("data", function (err) {                           
    socket.emit("error", "" + err);                                         
});                                                                         

proc.on("close", function (code) {                                
    socket.emit("finished", "" + code);                                     
});
```

I would like to avoid forcing terminal allocation for ssh via `-tt`.  Instead I would just like to allocate a terminal for the process.  Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

The [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) module allows setting of a pty used by the remote end when using shell() or exec().